# In a mucow file, is there a way to set the widget wdith as browserWidth by default?

Tags: xml, widget, muse

I'm making my own widget for Adobe Muse CC. Most of the time, this widget should get the same width that the browser window. Can I set the width default value as 'BrowserWidth' for a widget ?

Something like *defaultWidth="browserWidth"*

**my-widget.mucow**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<HTMLWidget name="my-widget" formatNumber="6" localization="none"  creator="Johan Maïa" supportedSizePolicies="fixed,browserWidth"  defaultHeight="32" defaultWidth="browserWidth" isResizable="false">
...
<HTMLWidget/>
```

Comment: Why would you force anyone to use your widget with a fixed width? Anyway I'm not sure about that, but I think it is not possible. You can manually set the container to stretch to the browser width.

Comment: @Core-Update  It's the actual state of my component.

Comment: Ok. Well it seems that it is really not possible... there is a post from last week on the adobe forum saying exactly that: https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2415764